# Сайт отображается только администратору

Tags: битрикс

Сайт на 1С-Битрикс отображается только администратору. Как только выхожу из учётной записи, показывается пустая страница. Как это исправить?

Comment: Какой именно сайт?

Comment: @Yarikhp, в логе ошибок сервера что пишут?

Comment: @Visman в логах ошибок Apache только строка server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name. Заметил что секция head выводится, а body нет.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько возможных вариантов:

1. Глобальный через админ-панель. Под администратором перейдите в "Настройки"-"Настройки модулей"-"Главный модуль" и в разделе "Служебные процедуры" проверьте состояние "Временное закрытие публичной части сайта". Там же есть кнопка управления состоянием.
2. Глобальный через код. Либо в init.php или еще где-то в коде программисты могли понаставить условий отображения.
3. Проверьте режим доступа у инфоблоков. Должен быть режим "для чтения". По-умолчанию у всех инфоблоков режим "нет доступа".

Comment: Сайт создавал сам, никто не мог поправить код. Указанные вами способы проверены, не помогло, но спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Проверьте код на наличие условия `if ($USER->IsAdmin())` и правильного закрытия условия. Могли использовать для вывода панели и неправильно закрыть.

Comment: Есть еще один вариант в настройках сайта `Настройки->Настройки продукта->Сайты->Список сайтов` в секции `Шаблоны сайтов` проверьте условия подключения шаблонов.